# Pass `this` value in constructor of subordinated module - typing

Tags: javascript, typescript, circular-dependency

I'm new to TypeScript and I try to upgrade my existed code from JS to TS.
How to fix this? Because for now it encounters circular dependencies problem.

Directory:

```
Main.ts
Helper.ts
```

Main Module:

```
import Helper from "./Helper"

export default class Main {
    helper:   Helper

    constructor() {
        this.helper = new Helper(this);
    }
}
```

Helper (Subordinated) Module:

```
import Main from "./Main"

export default class Helper {
    main: Main;

    constructor(main: Main) {
        this.main = main;
    }
}
```

Comment: Create next class for example MainWithHelper which could give as dependency this two classes but you must remove dependencies from this classes

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you are doing some 'circular' thing. You will need to think more on the classes behavior and the interaction between them. I highly recommend you to start `extend`ing classes, for example you can start creating subclasses from your Main:

Your **Main** class:

```
class Main {
  changeSomething(str) {
    console.log(str);
  }
}
```

Your **Helper** class:

```
import Main from "./Main";

class Helper extends Main {
  constructor() {
    super(); // Now you will have access to props and methods from Main class
  }

  launch() {
    this.changeSomething('wo!'); // Calling a parent method
  }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes methods/props names can collide, basically I'd like to split main class functionalities to some subclasses that works for main.